# Boolean object: value printed instead of the address

Tags: java

Greeting,
When I run the program below, false is printed instead of the address of the object "in". Any explanation, please? Thank you

```
public class test
{
public static void main(String[] ar)
{
Boolean in=new Boolean(false);
    System.out.println(in);
}
}
```

Comment: Because `Boolean` overrides the `toString()` method, which is used by the `println(Object)` method.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I should have checked the documentation